# Iterative Deepening A* graph with cycles implemenation

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have been trying to implement the Iterative Deepening A* algorithm where I have a graph with cycles .I have looked at the pseudo code of wikipedia found below :

```
 node              current node
 g                 the cost to reach current node
 f                 estimated cost of the cheapest path (root..node..goal)
 h(node)           estimated cost of the cheapest path (node..goal)
 cost(node, succ)  step cost function
 is_goal(node)     goal test
 successors(node)  node expanding function, expand nodes ordered by g + h(node)

 procedure ida_star(root)
   bound := h(root)
   loop
     t := search(root, 0, bound)
     if t = FOUND then return bound
     if t = ∞ then return NOT_FOUND
     bound := t
   end loop
 end procedure

 function search(node, g, bound)
   f := g + h(node)
   if f > bound then return f
   if is_goal(node) then return FOUND
   min := ∞
   for succ in successors(node) do
     t := search(succ, g + cost(node, succ), bound)
     if t = FOUND then return FOUND
     if t < min then min := t
   end for
   return min
 end function
```

However the problem is that this pseudocode does not deal with cycles as when entering a cycle the loop does not terminate.How can this be done ?

Comment: You can add an attribute "color" for each visited node, and then for each node, you check whether or not it is colored, ie already visited. If that is the case, then you don't continue in the loop.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the loop of the successors ?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you create two node lists and check them for each iteration:

**Open list:** Contains nodes that have not been expanded. Sorted by evaluation function **f(n) = g(n) + h(n)**. Initially contains the root. To expand a node you get the first one from the list. Besides you add the successors to the list.

**Closed list:** Contains nodes that have been expanded. When you are going to expand a node you check that it is not in the closed list. If it is you discard it.

Hope this helps.